# How to monitor and alter the value of decision variables using if then else

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

Assuming I have two 0-1 decision variables X[a,b] and Y[i,j,e,d] where :

X[a,b] =  1 if a is in b 0 otherwise

Y[i,j,e,d] = 1 if (i,j) is matched with (e,d) 0 otherwise.

I need to ensure that **if** two elements say k and l are both in f respectively i.e X[k,f] == 1 and X[l,f]==1 **then** **no matching** i.e **for each (e,d) Y[k,l,e,d] = 0.**

Knowing that my mathematical program is of type ILP, how do I write a constraint expressing the earlier statement ? Like I need to monitor both the value of the decision variables and the indices at the same time, is that possible to come up with a constraint ?

Highly appreciate your help.

Comment: At first you wrote, that variable Y accepts 4 'arguments' and then you write with only 2. What does it mean?

Comment: @SzymonStankiewicz You are right ! It was a mistake of typing. I corrected it now. Is that clear now ?

Comment: Maybe something like this?
$$\underset{f}{\forall}\;\;\underset{k,l}{\forall}\;\;\underset{e,d}{\forall}\;X_{k,f}+X_{l,f}+Y_{k,l,e,d}<3$$

Comment: @SzymonStankiewicz it worked well ! thanks a lot :). The thing is that instead of <3 I put <= 2 ;).